# Apache RewriteCondition: Check if attribute is set

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httprequest

For security reasons, we have a HTTP request where access is granted if the HTTP request (in our case it's called HTTP_IndividualAreaCode) is set to some number. It is however denied when it's empty. But if someone comes, who hasn't set this attribute at all, access is granted (this doesn't validate as true when checked for an attribute which equals to "").

How do I create a RewriteCond which also checks if the attribute is set at all (like isset in PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%{ENV:variable}` variable. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_IndividualAreaCode} [0-9]+
RewriteRule ^ /do/something [L]
```

Note that mod_rewrite my be executed before or after whatever module may be setting this environment variable. So this isn't always a guarantee that the var will be set when the rewrite engine executes this condition.